# Glassfish and JSP JasperException

Tags: jsp, glassfish-3

Hello everybody,

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

What does this mean? my jdk is installed and set correctly.
My servlets are working fine but calling my .jsp site causes
this Error.

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 2):

Add the path to your jdk to the file glassfish3/glassfish/config/asenv.bat

for Example:

```
set AS_JAVA=C:\jdk7
```